# Find The Number Of Outcomes

Tags: permutations, combinations

I understand how to find the number of outcomes using permutations and combinations, but then I thought to myself what happens when it involves both?

I will make a mock scenario to explain what I am asking:

> **There are 12 players on a local soccer team. The team needs a captain and two co-captains**.
>
> 1. How many different possible outcomes are there to see who the captain of the team is?
>
> 2. Suppose the captain of the team has already been chosen. Of the remaining 11 players, how many different possible outcomes are there to see who the two co-captains are?
>
> 3. How many different possible outcomes are there to see who the captain is as well as the two co-captains?

The answer to #1 is simple. Using a permutation, we get the number of outcomes to be $_{12}P_{1} = 12$.

The answer to #2 can be found in a similar manner. Using a combination, we get the number of outcomes to be ${11} \choose {2}$ $= 55$.

However, I am not sure how to figure out the answer to #3. I know that the order doesn't matter whether a player is the first co-captain or the second co-captain. But order does matter if a player is captain compared to being only a co-captain. Now I am aware that I can list out every possible outcome, but that would take a long time to figure out by hand. I'm looking for a mathematical way to find the number of outcomes.

Comment: Why do you use a *permutation* for captain ? Although numerically same, it is a *choose* problem. $\binom{12}1$. And the second part also follows naturally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick the captain ($12$) then pick the two co-captains from who's left ($55$).  Multiply to get $660$.